bs58.encode is not a function
I was going to generate Solana wallet with @solana/web3.js and encode keypair.secretKey to base58 with "bs" package.. but I got an error: TypeError: bs58.encode is not a function
const keypair = Keypair.generate();

    // Get the public key in base58 format
    const publicKey = keypair.publicKey.toBase58();

    // Get the private key and convert it to base58
    const privateKeyBase58 = bs58.encode(keypair.privateKey);

    // Address is the same as the public key in Solana
    const address = publicKey;

    console.log(publicKey);
    console.log(privateKeyBase58);
    console.log(address);
    console.log(keypair);


This likely has to do with how you're importing bs58. Please add that line too your question. (If you're not importing it, that's the reason it's not working)

This likely has to do with how you're importing bs58. Please add that line too your question. (If you're not importing it, that's the reason it's not working)

when I use bs58.default.encode(keypair.privateKey)
it worked well..

Glad this worked! You should probably also include how you are importing bs58 as that affects how you call it (someone who imports bs58differently won't be able to use your answer). Thanks!

If you are working in a TypeScript environment, ensure that you also installed the types for bs58. You can do this by running:
npm install --save @types/bs58

More details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bs58

Are you using the bs58 module https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58 because bs is another module that does something else?

yeah and I found the solution, thx :)
Answer: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/15824/23379
